# Grails UnitTest

Tags: grails

Hi (it is propably stupid question)

how can acquire Domain class from database in test?

```
class PollServiceTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {
    Integer id = 1

    void testSomething() {
       Teacher teacher1 = Teacher.get(id)
       assert teacher1 != null
    }
}
```

I always get null or

> No signature of method:
>   cz.jak.Teacher.get() is applicable for
>   argument types: (java.lang.Integer)
>   values: [1]

thanks a lot
Tom

Comment: once you've added mockDomain(Teacker), I expect your test will fail as teacher1 == null :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grails unit tests do not have access to the Grails environment so you have to mock your Domain objects.

```
void testSomething() {
    mockDomain(Teacher)
    def teacher = new Teacher(...)
    assertNotNull teacher.save(insert:true)
    assertNotNull country.countryId
    def found = Teacher.get(country.countryId)
}
```

Comment: Lloyd,Could Grails unittest access the test database to retrieve the database data via the domain class static method (list,count,etc) as the traditional unittest does(such as java junit test).

Answer (score 0):

There is an optional second parameter to mockDomain that takes a List.  If you pass in a list, then the get, list, save, update, delete methods will work on those objects in the List (if any).

```
void testSomething() {
    def teachers = []
    for (i in 0..9) {
      teachers.add(new Teacher(name: "teacher${it}"))
    }
    mockDomain Teacher, data

    Teacher t2 = Teacher.get(2)
    assertEquals "teacher2", t2.name
}
```